# Using python to write mysql query to csv, need to show field names

Tags: python, mysql, csv, mariadb, pymysql

I have the following:

```python
import MySQLdb as dbapi
import sys
import csv

dbServer='localhost'
dbPass='supersecretpassword'
dbSchema='dbTest'
dbUser='root'

dbQuery='SELECT * FROM pbTest.Orders;'

db=dbapi.connect(host=dbServer,user=dbUser,passwd=dbPass)
cur=db.cursor()
cur.execute(dbQuery)
result=cur.fetchall()

c = csv.writer(open("temp.csv","wb"))
c.writerow(result)
```

This produces a garbled mess. I am familiar with using printing record[0] etc. Not sure how I should be going about setting up the formatting. to produce something like what a query would in a console. I cannot do a simple INTO OUTFILE from the mysql server.

---

**Update**

It's been 8 years; I still get the occasional update or query about this question.

As stated in some of the comments, the [cursor.description](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#description) from the DBAPI is what I was looking for.

Here is a more modern example in Python 3 using the [pymysql](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) driver to connect to [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org), which will select and fetch all rows into a tuple, the row headers/description into a list. I then merge these two data structures into a single list, to be [written to a csv file](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html#csv.writer).

With the header names being the first entry in the result list; writing the result to a file in a linear fashion ensures the row header is the first line in the CSV file.

```python
import pymysql
import csv
import sys

db_opts = {
    'user': 'A',
    'password': 'C',
    'host': 'C',
    'database': 'D'
}

db = pymysql.connect(**db_opts)
cur = db.cursor()

sql = 'SELECT * from schema_name.table_name where id=123'
csv_file_path = '/tmp/my_csv_file.csv'

try:
    cur.execute(sql)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
finally:
    db.close()

# Continue only if there are rows returned.
if rows:
    # New empty list called 'result'. This will be written to a file.
    result = list()

    # The row name is the first entry for each entity in the description tuple.
    column_names = list()
    for i in cur.description:
        column_names.append(i[0])

    result.append(column_names)
    for row in rows:
        result.append(row)

    # Write result to file.
    with open(csv_file_path, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        for row in result:
            csvwriter.writerow(row)
else:
    sys.exit("No rows found for query: {}".format(sql))
```

Answer (score 44):

You can dump all results to the csv file without looping:

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
fp = open('/tmp/file.csv', 'w')
myFile = csv.writer(fp)
myFile.writerows(rows)
fp.close()
```

Comment: Great answer.  I would just change the 'file' variable to something like myfile since 'file' is a keyword.

Comment: This works great but is there anyway I could get the field names/column names as well please.

Comment: Thanks, found this very handy.

Comment: @JakeWagner add `writer.writeheader()` before `writerows()`

Comment: my csv doesn't show correctly. it doesn't fill the cell just straight lines

Comment: Thanks  for the answer but if you add newline='' to open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') it will stop it adding a CR under each line of the output.

Answer (score 19):

Answer with column header names for anyone who comes across this:
(I am using Jwhat's method to write to csv)

```
result = cur.fetchall()

#Getting Field Header names
column_names = [i[0] for i in cur.description]
fp = open('Result_Set.csv' 'w')
myFile = csv.writer(fp, lineterminator = '\n') #use lineterminator for windows
myFile.writerow(column_names)
myFile.writerows(result)
fp.close()
```

Answer (score 18):

`result` is a list of rows. So you'll need to iterate through that list and write each row:

```
for row in result:
    c.writerow(row)
```

Comment: that's great thanks, any idea how I can write out the field names too?

Comment: @teatime - You can get the fieldnames from `result[0].keys` (or equivalently `row.keys`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer doesn't completely answer the question's title ("need to show field names"). @mtrw's comment helps, but is not applicable to the code given (tuple object has no attribute 'keys'). It might be applicable if the cursor were a dictionary cursor, i.e. created using `dbconn.cursor(dictionary=True)`.

Comment: When using a dictionary cursor, `result[0].keys()` gives a list of column names. However it is not (generally) in the same order as you would get from `result[0]` for a non-dictionary cursor, nor the same order as you would see in a MySQL client. In short, it's a mess. If the column order doesn't matter, this might be OK.

Answer (score 8):

The previous answer would give an error.  The header must be written to the file first, then the rows added. The following worked for me.

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
headers = [col[0] for col in cursor.description] # get headers
rows.insert(0, tuple(headers))
fp = open('/tmp/file.csv', 'w', newline = '') 
myFile = csv.writer(fp)
myFile.writerows(rows)
fp.close()
```

Comment: Why you are adding header and with rows ?  This will write the headers twice.

Answer (score 3):

Just add one more thing to @jwhat answer.

If you intend to open this csv file in windows, you will need to handle the extra empty lines.

just change the code to the following, as the default lineterminator in 2.7 is \r\n

```
myFile = csv.writer(fp, lineterminator='\n')
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been open excel and removing the blank lines from there , and it was always a pain, and I never figured out to stop it.

Answer (score 1):

I know little python, but after a bit of googling, should you be using writerows (with an S) which writes multiple rows, rather than writerow which expects a single row.

As I say this is a bit of a stab in the dark from me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pymysql
import sys
import csv

connection = pymysql.connect(host='abcde',
user='admin',
password='secret',
db='databaseName',
port=12345)

dbQuery="SELECT field1, field2, fieldn FROM database.table;"
cur=connection.cursor()
cur.execute(dbQuery)
rows=cur.fetchall()
column_names = [i[0] for i in cur.description]
fp = open('DimDevice.csv', 'w')
myFile = csv.writer(fp, lineterminator = '\n')
myFile.writerow(column_names)   
myFile.writerows(rows)
fp.close()
```