# connectorx connect Oracle by TNS entry name instead of connection string

Tags: python, oracle

[connectorx](https://sfu-db.github.io/connector-x/intro.html) is a fast read_sql python library, I can use it to connect Oracle by connection string `conn = 'oracle://username:password@server:port/database'` , but How I can use tns entry name in connectorx, in cx_Oracle, it can be done like this: `conn = cx_Oracle.connect(dsn="the_tns_entry_name")`. Is there similar way to do it in connectorx? Since in my tns entry, it doesn't need user id and password, seems like Windows Authentication. So I want to use it without specifying uid and pwd.

I am expecting to know how to use connectorx to link Oracle by tns entry name or by window authentication.

Comment: If performance is important, use cx_Oracle APIs calls directly.  Or better, use the latest version which is now called python-oracledb, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).  The thin mode can be faster than cx_Oracle. I think connectorx won't overcome DB design limitations: see [Selecting from an Oracle Database table in parallel using Python](https://medium.com/oracledevs/selecting-from-an-oracle-database-table-in-parallel-using-python-31ecaa2c28c8) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/75662130/4799035